# UIview layout not autosizing for iPhone retina 4 inch screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, layout, uiview

Xcode 5 storyboard app. 
When I tap on button in the app, choosing a property - UIView opens, but only shows the correct layout for the first View.
When swiping left/right - the layout of all views is fine. The problem only happens when I tap on any button, except the first one. All the settings for all views and all code in .h and .m files are equal.

I use iCarousel for swipes.

Screenshots will help you to understand the problem better:

1. Right:
   ![Correct layout]
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0HEP.jpg
2. Wrong: (see blank space at the top and bottom)
   ![Incorrect one - has to look like Pic.1]
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqTmH.png

   I don't want to mess with auto layout because scrollviews doesn't work properly with it. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out if this works. I too had a issue of same kind where the position of top and bottom margin has shifted. I used this in viewDidLoad method.

```
if( [self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)] ) 
{    
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone; 
}

or else set frame for iPhone retina 4 inch screen like this   
if(IS_IPHONE_5)
{
     tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 560); // something like this in DidLoad method or in viewWillAppear method
}
```

Comment: The first option doesn't make any changes. And the second shows error: Use of undeclared identifier Is_Iphone_5. What should I do to get rid of this error? Any other options to solve my problem?

Comment: you have to define it like this.. and set the frame size as defined above..                                                        #define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)